# Error Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) installing PyQt6

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt6

Hi im trying to install PyQt6 (with pip) in a venv with Python 3.9.4 x86 but im keep getting this error message

```
Collecting pyqt6
  Using cached PyQt6-6.2.3.tar.gz (1.0 MB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [29 lines of output]
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "D:\Proyectos\software_estudio_2.0\venv_x32\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\in_process\_in_process.py", line 156, in prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel
          hook = backend.prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel
      AttributeError: module 'sipbuild.api' has no attribute 'prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel'
 
  During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
 
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "D:\Proyectos\software_estudio_2.0\venv_x32\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\in_process\_in_process.py", line 363, in <module>     
      main()
    File "D:\Proyectos\software_estudio_2.0\venv_x32\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\in_process\_in_process.py", line 345, in main
      json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
    File "D:\Proyectos\software_estudio_2.0\venv_x32\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\in_process\_in_process.py", line 160, in prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel
      whl_basename = backend.build_wheel(metadata_directory, config_settings)
    File "C:\Users\rober\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-skgk91v2\overlay\Lib\site-packages\sipbuild\api.py", line 51, in build_wheel
      project = AbstractProject.bootstrap('pep517')
    File "C:\Users\rober\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-skgk91v2\overlay\Lib\site-packages\sipbuild\abstract_project.py", line 83, in bootstrap
      project.setup(pyproject, tool, tool_description)
    File "C:\Users\rober\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-skgk91v2\overlay\Lib\site-packages\sipbuild\project.py", line 594, in setup
      self.apply_user_defaults(tool)
    File "project.py", line 67, in apply_user_defaults
      super().apply_user_defaults(tool)
    File "C:\Users\rober\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-skgk91v2\overlay\Lib\site-packages\pyqtbuild\project.py", line 70, in apply_user_defaults
      super().apply_user_defaults(tool)
    File "C:\Users\rober\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-skgk91v2\overlay\Lib\site-packages\sipbuild\project.py", line 241, in apply_user_defaults
      self.builder.apply_user_defaults(tool)
    File "C:\Users\rober\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-skgk91v2\overlay\Lib\site-packages\pyqtbuild\builder.py", line 67, in apply_user_defaults
      raise PyProjectOptionException('qmake',
  sipbuild.pyproject.PyProjectOptionException
  [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.
```

I have no problem installing it in the same venv with a 3.9.4 x64 version. Is possible that PyQt6 is not compatible with x86 pyhton's versions? Is there any solution?

Comment: That can't be the *entire* error you are getting? if so post the entire stacktrace

Comment: @RobertoDiBartolomeo if you call your mechanic saying "my car doesn't work, call me back to tell me what's wrong" they will never call you. We cannot help you if you leave out the most important aspect of your question: *the error*. Please take your time to review the [tour], read [ask] and also the [checklist](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260648).

Comment: Sorry @DeepSpace im kinda new in this, just edited the post with the entire error message.

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem when I wanted to install PyQt5-tools.I used Python 3.10.2 and then I removed it and install Python 3.9.10 ( without upgrading pip from 21.2.4 to 22.0.3) and problem solved.

Comment: Hi, in PyQt5 that works, but in PyQt6 does not, i think PyQt6 just does not work with a x86 windows system.